# PHP convert ARGB to RGBA?

Tags: php, colors, rgba, argb

Need solution or description of: How to convert color value from ARGB to RGBA which is possible to use for css:

**Examples:**

```
ARGB color : #ff502797 convert to RGBA
RGBA result example: rgba(80,39,151,1)
```

thx.

Comment: "which is possible to use for html" Did you mean CSS?

Comment: 1) split argb color value into individual components, 2) convert components to decimal values, 3) output as rgba() string.

Comment: Yes, but need "map" of spit... I fond and wrote bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ARGB** contains 4 groups of HEX values(channels): Alpha, Red, Green, Blue.

**Scheme:**
Exampe: #ff502797 - color in ARGB formatt
Elements on positions:

```
0,1 - Alpa  (ff)
2,3 - Red   (50)
4,5 - Green (27)
6,7 - Blue  (97)
```

After this convert each channel to decimal. And putt on their places into **RBGA**:
**rgba(Red,Green,Blue,Alpha)** - rgba(80,39,151,1)

**Example function:**

```
function argb2rgba($color)
    {
        $output = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)';

        if (empty($color))
            return $output;

        if ($color[0] == '#') {
            $color = substr($color, 1);
        }

        if (strlen($color) == 8) { //ARGB
            $opacity = round(hexdec($color[0].$color[1]) / 255, 2);
            $hex = array($color[2].$color[3], $color[4].$color[5], $color[6].$color[7]);
            $rgb = array_map('hexdec', $hex);
            $output = 'rgba(' . implode(",", $rgb) . ',' . $opacity . ')';
        }

        return $output;
    }
```